# Can we use generics for method arguments in java

Tags: java, generics, overloading

Instead of using overloading I want to use single method with generic datatypes like,

```
public void setValues(T key, T value){
    if(key instanceof Integer){
        //code
    }elseif(key instanceof String){
       //code
    }else{
     //code
    }
}
```

Is there any way to achieve this.

Comment: You can, but don't you see how ugly your method becomes?

Comment: You don't need generics here, just use `Object` as parameters.

Comment: You can but need to declare the method as generic : `public <T> void setValues(T key, T value)`. But I agree with previous commenters : it's not justified in the case you described.

Comment: @Kayaman we are having multiple methods with same functionality for different datatypes, that's why I am collaborating it in single method.

Comment: @JornVernee Yes I could have used Object but wanted to make it generic

Comment: @ÉricRoberge Thank you. This is exactly what I wanted

Comment: I hope someone paid top dollar for this code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You define the type T in your method

So any method you want generic you have a signature like this

`public void <T> someMethod (T arg)`

Comment: Thank you @ÉricRoberge This is exactly what I wanted

Comment: @VikasYadav Accept the answer if it solved your issue

Answer (score 1):

Based on your question I wrote a small application. It compiles, runs and produces the expected output but I'm complete puzzled how it works:

```
public class Ff {
    public static <T> void setValue(T key, T value)
    {
        key=value;
        System.out.println(key);
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        setValue(1L,"hello");
    }
}
```

Output:

> hello

Comment: More specifically instead of forcing both `T`s to be the same type as you might expect, `T` is chosen to be wide enough so that both of the parameters are accepted.